# Strange behaviour in bash when extracting arn for a resource

Tags: bash, aws-cli

having to update a number of resources (dynamoDbTables) with some tags I've found that, if I get the arn this way (in a for loop)

```
T_ARN=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $TABLE --query=Table.TableArn)
```

and then I use it this way

```
$(aws dynamodb tag-resource --resource-arn ${T_ARN} --tags Key=CentroDiCosto,Value=SomeValue)
```

The tag call fails with

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the TagResource operation: Invalid TableArn: Invalid ResourceArn provided as input "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx:table/yyyyyy"
```

After some debug I found that to make the call work I had to 'clean up'  the arn value returned from the first call,

```
# this doesn't work
...
T_ARN=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $TABLE --query=Table.TableArn)
...
$(aws dynamodb tag-resource --resource-arn ${T_ARN} --tags Key=CentroDiCosto,Value=SomeValue)
...
```

```
# this works
...
T_ARN=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $TABLE --query=Table.TableArn)
...
#here i strip away the extra "
U_ARN=$(echo $T_ARN|sed -e 's/"//g')
...
$(aws dynamodb tag-resource --resource-arn ${U_ARN} --tags Key=CentroDiCosto,Value=SomeValue)
```

can someone suggest a more clean and elegant way to work with this king of issues?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JSON output.  Change to text and you'll be good to do.

```
T_ARN=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $TABLE --query=Table.TableArn --output text)
```

Example Output

```
$ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name acme --query=Table.TableArn
"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:717475838310:table/acme"

$ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name acme --query=Table.TableArn --output text
arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:717475838310:table/acme
```

Comment: You are right!! It was the egg of Columbus :-) 
Thank you!

Comment: And today I learned about the egg of Columbus.  So a thank you back and your welcome.